# How to store characters in a 2D character array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a 2D array that stores character values and I keep running into errors. Here's the code I have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] text;
        text = new char[20][45];

        // Enter your message into the array

        char text[][] = {{A, ,b,i,g, },{d,o,g, ,a,t,e},{ ,a, ,p,i,g}};

        java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (char column = 0; column < text[0].length; column++) {
            for (char row = 0; row < text.length; row++) {
                System.out.println(text[row][column] + " " );

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

I am also trying to print the values in column major order. How do I make this 2D array store letters? When I put letters into the array I get an error saying "A cannot be resolved to a variable, b cannot be resolved to a variable, etc." How do I set the array up so it can store these values and not result in errors?

Comment: These are basic syntax errors that the compiler is catching. You need to put characters in single quotes, otherwise the compiler tries to resolve them as variable names.

Answer (score 2):

A quick answer with thanks to @Kon in the comments:
Characters ***need*** to have quotes around them. If I execute

```
char[][] text;
text = new char[20][45];
char text[][] = {{h, i},{ ,b , o ,b}};
```

Firstly, I would already get the error `Duplicate local variable text` because you are defining text 2 times: One when you say `char[][] text;` and the other time when you say `char text[][] =`. Assuming you fixed that and put the right code, you still have a problem:
***YOU DON'T HAVE THE CHARACTERS RIGHT*** Next time, do this

```
{{'h', 'i'}, {' ', 'b', 'o', 'b'}}
```

Instead of

```
{{h, i}, { , b, o, b}}
```

Comment: **ahem** single quotes for characters

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I had to do this fast, so I accidentally typed double quotes